# dojo layout tutorial for version 1.7 doesn't work for 1.7.2

Tags: layout, dojo

This is sortof a continuation to [dojo1.7 layout acting screwy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248427/dojo1-7-layout-acting-screwy).

So I made some working widgets and tested them out, i then tried altering my work using the tutorial at http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/dijit_layout/ to make the layout nice. After failing at that in many interesting ways (thus my last question) I started on a new path. My plan is now to implement the layout tutorial example and then stick in my widgets. For some reason even following the tutorial wont work... everything loads then disappears and I'm left with a blank browser window.

Any ideas?

It just struck me that it could be browser compatibility issues, I'm working on Firefox 13.0.1. As far as I know Dojo is supposed to be compatible with this...

anyway, have some code:

HTML:

```
<body class="claro">
<div
        id="appLayout" class="demoLayout"
        data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
        data-dojo-props="design: 'headline'">
    <div
            class="centerPanel"
            data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
            data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
        <div>
            <h4>Group 1 Content</h4>
            <p>stuff</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>Group 2 Content</h4>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>Group 3 Content</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div
            class="edgePanel"
            data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
            data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">
                Header content (top)
    </div>
    <div
        id="leftCol" class="edgePanel"
        data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
        data-dojo-props="region: 'left', splitter: true">
            Sidebar content (left)
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Dojo Configuration:

```
var dojoConfig = {
        baseUrl: "${request.static_url('mega:static/js')}", //this is in a mako template
        tlmSiblingOfDojo: false,
        packages: [
            { name: "dojo", location: "libs/dojo" },
            { name: "dijit", location: "libs/dijit" },
            { name: "dojox", location: "libs/dojox" },
        ],
        parseOnLoad: true,
        has: {
                "dojo-firebug": true,
                "dojo-debug-messages": true
            },   
       async: true 
    };
```

other js stuff:

```
require(["dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/parser"]);
```

css:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
}

#appLayout {
height: 100%;
}
#leftCol {
width: 14em;
}
```

Comment: anything interesting in firebug? you should also remove `,` from the last argument in your `packages` config option.

Comment: nothing interesting: all the divs are there, no errors have shown up, no evidence of mismatched tags. I've taken out that comma, thanks. It didn't seem to change anything though

Comment: can you see the source once the page is loaded? maybe it's the css issue? try to remove `class` attribute. I believe you added proper css declaration for `claro` theme? layout from tutorial works fine with dojo 1.7.2 in firefox aurora 15 - I can guarantee that from my own experience ; )

Comment: That is very reassuring :) I removed all the class attributes to no avail... Also, claro is included, and a little bit of extra css stuff. I've included it at the bottom of the q for completeness but it doesn't do anything fancy

Comment: @Sheena is your css really beginning with `tml, body` ?

Comment: @hb40: nope, that was a typo, fixed it

Comment: @Sheena glad to help.  If you don't mind I'll make it regular answer.  Having unresolved questions that are actually answered drives me crazy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest viewing the 'complete demo' on the tutorial page and then use firebug to compare your code to the example. Often they'll leave out an additional 'demo.css' file or something else that you actually need to stitch everything together.